# Remove rows with missing values in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I want to remove all rows with NAs, I tried na.omit, but I still have all the "#N/A" values in my data...

This is my code:

```
mydata = read.csv('file:///C:/Users/file.csv')
mydata = as.data.frame(mydata)
mydata[mydata$col2== "#N/A"] <- "NA"
na.omit(mydata$col2)
```

What can I do?

I also tried this:

```
mydata = mydata[!is.na(mydata)]
```

But it doesn't work either

Answer (score 4):

You should instruct R to treat the string `#N/A` as `NA` immediately. The argument `na.strings` to `read.csv` tells R what strings to treat as `NA`.

```
mydata <- read.csv('file:///C:/Users/file.csv', na.strings = c("", "NA", "#N/A"))
mydata[complete.cases(mydata), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `complete.cases` function

```
mydata = mydata[complete.cases(mydata), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. It's usually best to specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` using `read.csv` (unless you really want factors)
2. There's no need to use `as.data.frame` after `read.csv`, you already have a data frame
3. In the third line you need a comma before the closing `]`
4. You're replacing with the string "NA", just use `NA` (no quotes)
5. To remove rows from data frame `mydata`, just use `na.rm(mydata)`, not `mydata$col2`

   ```
   mydata = read.csv('file:///C:/Users/file.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   mydata[mydata$col2 == "#N/A", ] <- NA
   na.omit(mydata)
   ```